# Singular noun with no article as generic noun

Tags: grammar, articles, zero-article

According to the grammar book I'm reading, the sentence

> **The telephone** rules my life.

is not about a particular telephone, but the general concept. I was wondering what happens if we omit the article 'the' here ("Telephone rules my life.") Is the new sentence grammatical? If so, how is the meaning changed?

I know that 'the' with a plural noun makes the phrase specific. For example 'I love books' refers to books in general, while 'I love the books' is about a particular set of books. However, in the sentence above 'the' is not used with a plural noun ('telephone').

Comment: If you use the plural ("Telephones rule my life") it would make sense and be speaking about telephones in general, but just "Telephone" can't be used alone like that.

Comment: I can, however, say that television rules my life.

Comment: @Esther, what if I replace "Telephone" with an uncountable noun: "Sugar rules my life"?

Comment: @apadana that works as well

Comment: Interesting. Uncountable nouns seem to work without an article, whereas countable nouns (like "telephone") need an article or to be pluralized to get the point across. But as @MichaelHarvey points out, certain countable nouns like "television" work without the article... how do we explain that? It might have something to do with the fact that "television" alone often means "the act of watching television" whereas the same isn't true for "telephone."

Comment: @cruthers - These days I sometimes might use 'television' in the same way that I have been using 'cinema' for decades. It doesn't rule my life, though. That's done by Linux.